# Programatically set an ASP.NET website bindings for an IIS7 site?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, binding

i've got a simple ASP.NET website that i end up publishing/running on an IIS7 server.

Is it possible to to add into my web.config file some 'binding' information, instead of having to set it manually through the site in IIS7.

eg. imagine i have the following bindings

1. http://foo.mysite.com 80
2. http://bar.mysite.com 80
3. http://www.mysite.com 80

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on the IIS forums [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1160837.aspx) :-

> Although binding configuration is
>   updated at an individual web-site
>   level, the binding configuration
>   information is stored in the server's
>   applicationHost.config file, not in
>   the individual web.config files under
>   each web site. Allowing individual
>   web-site owners to change the bindings
>   for their web sites is a security
>   risk.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can from web.config.

But if you have some automatic deployment, you can do like this:

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/05/16/programmatically-creating-an-iis7-site.aspx

Comment: i'm thinking it's only available for the applicationhost file level, not web config level :( It's more about maintenance each time the site is published - so if we need to add or change a binding, the sites are updated when i publish to live. This is very important for me cause we're in a large web farm. Do it once, boom all updated.