# Add site bindings to IIS 7.5 programmatically

Tags: winapi, binding, iis-7

I have a web application that requires multiple domains to point to the same site in IIS. I would like to be able to do this from a web interface but that would mean adding site bindings programmatically.

Im sure applications like Plesk access some sort of Windows API to do it, I just dont know how.

A related post is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408312/programatically-set-an-asp-net-website-bindings-for-an-iis7-site) but it doesnt solve this specific problem.

Comment: Have you checked this page? http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but if you are using .NET you can use [ServerManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class from the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace you can add bindings like so:

```
using (ServerManager manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("serverName"))
{
    manager.Sites["mySiteName"].Bindings.Add("*:80:domain.com", "http");
    manager.CommitChanges();
}
```

So in the example above the * means the IP to match to, 80 is the port, and domain.com is the host header. To add https bindings is a bit more involved and you need to load the certificate programatically.